# Why is today`s weekday pluss two not working?

Tags: php, date

Any reason why `$daynames[$dayW +1]` works and displays todays dayname +1, but not `$daynames[$dayW +2]`?
I am trying to display days in the week +1 day in the first and +2 days in the second cell, but I get an error on the +2 line.

```
$daynames = array("Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag");

$dayW = date("w");

<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW];?></td>
<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW +1];?></td>
<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW +2];?></td>
<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW +3];?></td>
<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW +4];?></td>
<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW +5];?></td>
<td><?php echo $daynames[$dayW +6];?></td>
```

Comment: Your code will work... only if today is Sunday :)

Comment: Anyway, what are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you trying to print out the name of the day which n days from now?

Comment: When today is Satursday, the $dayW will becomes 6.  Your array only has 7 elements (0 to 6), so if you are trying to get the element 6+2 of the array , it will be array index out of bounds (a case of the buffer overflow)

Comment: ok, I see why this doesn't work. When today is Friday (number 6) +2 is nothing in the array because it's only 7 items in the array. I am trying to print every day for 7 days (from today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to print what is the day name when you add a number of days to a given day right ? If true, I think you might need to look for the modulo function (cf. https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.arithmetic.php)
Basically here, the principle is that every time you add 7 days, you get the same day name; so you need a modulo 7.

Here is your code slightly altered to show this in action :

```php
<?php

$daynames = array("Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag");

$dayW = date("w");



echo "## 1) First method : just tweaking your code" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[$dayW % 7] . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[($dayW +1) % 7] . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[($dayW +2) % 7] . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[($dayW +3) % 7] . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[($dayW +4) % 7] . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[($dayW +5) % 7] . PHP_EOL;
echo $daynames[($dayW +6) % 7] . PHP_EOL;
```

You can also see that in action here https://3v4l.org/6daZo with another slightly sophisticated variation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following logic to print the next seven days in table format:

The function `printNextSevenDays($dayW, $daynames);` takes two parameters, the current day of the week `$dayW` and the array with the weekdays `$daynames`.
It returns an array, `$days`, that contains the next 7 days (starting today).

The array is printed in table format, building the cells and injecting the resulting HTML into a [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) with basic table HTML.

```
<?php
$daynames = array("Sonntag", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag");

$dayW = date("w");

$days = printNextSevenDays($dayW, $daynames);

// build table cells
$data = '';
foreach($days as $day) {
    $data .= "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $day . "</td>";
}
// render table
echo <<<HEREDOC
<table><tr>$data</tr></table>
HEREDOC;


function printNextSevenDays($dayW = 0, $dayNames = []): array
{
    $days = [];
    for($i=0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        if ($dayW + $i <= 6) {
            $days[] = $dayNames[$dayW + $i];
        } else {
            $days[] = $dayNames[$dayW + $i - 7];
        }
    }
    return $days;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This print today+ each day for 6 days like I want. But can I divide the output so I can use it in a table? Example today´s dayname is in the first cell, and tomorrow´s dayname in the second etc..